# how to give two view in one master view in ipad?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want two tableviews in one master view. My application is run only in landscape mode. On the left side is the first tableview, and on the right side is the second table view. I have these two now.

I need to call 4 more extra view on the right side. But this view call should come from the left side table view, because on the left side, a list of view names is diplayed. If i click any cell, thn right side view should show that view which I clicked.

I am not using splitview and I don't want a splitview in this application, so how can I call that view from the left side?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use two tables, one on left side and second on right side:
tableview1.tag = 0;
tableview.tag = 2;

Just reload the table view with tag = 2 while clicking on any row on left side table

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        {
     if (tableView.tag == 1)
                return 5;
            else if (tableView.tag == 2)
                return 10;
        }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            static NSString *identifier = @"CellIdentifier";    
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

            }
            if (tableView.tag == 1)
            {
        ///// Do whatever you want to do
            }
            else if (tableView.tag == 2)
            {
        ///// Do whatever you want to do
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = @"example";       
            return cell;
        }
```